# How to play mp3 while running a process in the background in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying an widows form application which runs a process that redirects the output of an C++ exe to the C# application in real time. The redirected C++ output is then used to trigger several tasks. For example: if redirected output is equal to "playSong" it should play the mp3 file. The C++ output redirection is working fine as I have already used it to trigger other tasks such opening and closing form windows, but only for playing the mp3 it doesn't work and the code after that seems to work too. (Also I'm using openCV in the C++ program if that matters to the problem) However I tried playing the mp3 in different project without using any process and there the mp3 plays fine. It would be great if anyone can help me with this and here is how I have tried.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class frmPlayList : Form
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

    public bool flag = true;
    static string varr2;

    public frmPlayList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void frmPlayList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.getProcess().OutputDataReceived += processOutputDataReceived2;
    }
    public void processOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        varr2 = e.Data;

        if (varr2 == "playSong" && flag)
        {
            playSong();
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    public delegate void UpdateControlsDelegate();

    public void playSong() //Playing song
    {
        InvokeUpdateControlsForPlaySong();
    }
    public void InvokeUpdateControlsForPlaySong()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateControlsDelegate(UpdateControlsForPlaySong));
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateControlsForPlaySong();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateControlsForPlaySong()
    {
        string f = @"path\a.mp3";
        mciSendString("open \"" + f + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.WriteLine("Song ended!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't answer your question but in your place I'd try using a different method to play the mp3 file. Maybe the winmm and mciSendString are interfering with your c++ to c# connection. Also, did you consider just using your c++ code in the c# program instead of running two processes in parallel?

Comment: Try using NAudio library, this intended to work with audio files and easy of use

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the media player ?? just hide it !!

Comment: yeah, I used the windows media player with wmplib. Thanks for the help